# Send parameters in order in HTTPService

Tags: apache-flex, parameters, httpservice

I am trying to work with a simple HTTPService. The problem is that my webservice is conscious of the order of arguments it gets. I will tell the problem with an example:

```
var service:HTTPService = new HTTPService(); 
var params:Object = new Object(); 
params.rows = 0;
params.facet = "true"; 
service.send(params);
```

Note that in the above code I have mentioned the parameter **rows** before **facet**, but the url I recieve is `facet=true&rows=0`. So I recieve the argument rows before facet and hence my webservice does not work. I figured out that the contents of array is always sent in alphabetical order, which I dont want.

Is there any way I can achieve explict ordering of parameters sent?

Note that I am not in power of changing the logic of webservice(its basically a RPC service supporting both desktop and web client).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using a get method. Instead of passing params to the HTTPService, build a url string. You can pass get params just by changing that string then calling the service.

```
service.url = "originalURL" + "?" + "rows=0" + "&" + "facet=true";
service.send();
```

Comment: i knew this already...but was wondering there was a more flexible way of doing it instead of hardcoding the url. As of now, I thin kI have to stick with this.